# answer of this code is coming as false for every input whether it is correct or wrong

Tags: java, regex

I want the regex output false for wrong input and true for right input but only false is displaying on the output. This is the program of Java Regex of "Create a regular expression that accepts 10 digit numeric characters 
 starting with 7, 8 or 9 only".

This is the code of jdk 1.8.0

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String st="";
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    st=sc.nextLine();
    boolean result=Pattern.matches("[7,8,9]{1}[0-9]{9}","st");
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: You mean st without quotes `Pattern.matches("[789]{1}[0-9]{9}",st);`

Comment: You could shorten it to `[789][0-9]{9}` You don't need to add a comma to the character class or else it would be matched literally.

Comment: After removing the qoutes on st the output is coming right can you tell me why the qoutes are not required over st but it is the important syntax of regex?

Comment: ok. What is the purpose of getting the user input and pointing it with variable 'st'? In the next line, you are using the string literal instead of the variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently with are searching pattern in a String with value `"st"` instead of value of local variable `st`

Change your line:

```
boolean result = Pattern.matches("[789]{1}[0-9]{9}",st);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are always comparing to the string literal st instead of the reference to the line you read.

instead of `boolean result=Pattern.matches("[7,8,9]{1}[0-9]{9}","st");`
use `boolean result=Pattern.matches("[789][0-9]{9}",st);`

Answer (score 1):

These expressions would also work:

```
boolean result = Pattern.matches("[7-9][0-9]{9}", st);
```

or

```
boolean result = Pattern.matches("[789][0-9]{9}", st);
```

Also, maybe if we'd add ^ and $ anchors, that'd be OK too:

```
^[789][0-9]{9}$
^[789]\d{9}$
```

#### [Please see the demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/5ojTzf/1/)